# Is it possible to completely ignore children when using events in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, addeventlistener

I've been working on task organization website at work and i've hit a roadblock. I'm trying to create a [tasklist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6xrC.png) which holds cards (similar to how trello works). I've managed to get the cards to correctly drag & drop, and it works just as it should. However, my issue comes with an [indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vb0Cg.png) that shows up when a card is hovered over by the dragged card. I've designed the indicator to activate when the drop target is entered. This works, until a child element within the drop target, is entered. Once that happens, the indicator freaks out, and only gets fixed when you exit the card, and re-enter(assuming you don't also enter a child element).

So, what I need is a way to ignore children and only see the parent element. I tried various methods with stopping both capturing and bubbling before they reach the children, but this didn't help. The children still forced the held card to believe it exited the drop target.

Since my code is pretty long, i'll just include a few lines from the javascript. Keep in mind, I'm semi new to web development, so my javascript may not follow the best practices. Originally, the code was better maintained and prettier to look at, but since i've been trying so many methods of ignoring children, it has got a bit hectic.

Anyway, any pointers would be awesome. Thanks in advance!

```js
function addListeners(card)
{
    //takes the interior card and adds listeners.
    card.draggable = true;
    card.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    $(card).on('click', card, function() { editCard(card) });

    card.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart, false);
    card.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd, false);
    card.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter, false);
    card.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver, false);
    card.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave, false);
    card.addEventListener('drop', dragDrop, false);
    //event.currentTarget !== event.target

    return card;
}

function dragStart()
{
    originalClassname = this.className;
    this.className += ' holding';
    this.id = 'dragged-card';
    previousStyle = this.parentNode.style.display;
    setTimeout(() => (this.parentNode.style.display = 'none'), 10);
}

function dragEnd() 
{
    this.className = originalClassname;
    this.parentNode.style.display = previousStyle;
}

function dragEnter(e) 
{
    console.log("enter");
    var enteredElement = e.currentTarget.parentNode;
    var dropIndicator = enteredElement.querySelector("#drop-indicator");
    dropIndicator.className += ' indicator-active';
}

function dragOver(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
}

function dragLeave(e) 
{
    console.log(e.currentTarget.parentNode);
    if (e.currentTarget.parentNode === enteredElement)
    {
        var dropIndicator = e.currentTarget.parentNode.querySelector("#drop-indicator");
        dropIndicator.className = 'drop-indicator';
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Still in element.");
    }
}

function dragDrop(e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var dropIndicator = e.currentTarget.parentNode.querySelector("#drop-indicator");
    var draggedCard = document.getElementById('dragged-card');
    tasklist.insertBefore(draggedCard.parentNode, this.parentNode);
    dropIndicator.className = 'drop-indicator';
    draggedCard.id = '';

}
```

A few notes. The cards are created dynamically and get parented to the tasklist. That card ends up in this form:

```html
<div id="card" style="">
    <div class="drop-indicator" id="drop-indicator"></div>
    <div class="card card-sizer" draggable="true" style="cursor: pointer;" id="">
        <span class="card-label" id="card-label" style="background: rgb(250, 86, 86);"></span>
        <info class="card-info">
            <h3 id="card-title">Stuff</h3>
            <p id="card-description">Thaangs</p>
        </info>
    </div>
</div>
```

The interior card, with class card is what gets passed to the event listener function.

Comment: You might want to create a fiddle to show the problem. Also, are you re-using `id`s on all cards (like `drop-indicator`, `card-label`, `card-title`, and `card-description`)? Maybe these should be classes?

Comment: There's definitely a lot of refactoring I should and will do, but at the moment, unless it's needed for the problem at hand, I'm not going to worry about it. Do you know if it's possible to make events completely disregard the children?

Comment: You can manually check in the event handler that the target is the parent and not any of the child nodes. You can do so by checking the presence of an attribute that the parent has which the children do not have (e.g. class name).

Comment: if you have multiple cards then you have to make the id unique for each card. That's not refactoring rather it's most probably adding to your problem. IDs can only be used once on each page.

Comment: @FrankFajardo, Okay, that makes sense now why both you and cloned were mentioning the IDs. Assuming I make card IDs unique, I could simply check if the child's parent id is equal to the currentTarget. That's kind of what I had tried previously, but it will probably be easier if I add unique IDs.

Comment: @KnightSteele `id` attributes are intended to be unique identifiers. See https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute. As for your other question, if you check by `id`, how do you check all the `id`s in all your cards (unless you check for a partial id)? It is best to check for a class, which is generally what classes are for--to describe the same set of things. See https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#classes